# Hide push notification for particular message

Tags: apple-push-notifications, swift4

Is it possible to hide push notification for particular push notification message. We have push notification for location update. It will keep coming and from that data, we have to update in map. We have to hide push notification for particular push message(Here I mean location update push message).

Answer (score 0):

You must use silent notification for such message.

**Configuring silent notifications**

> To support silent remote notifications, add the remote-notification value to the UIBackgroundModes array in your Info.plist file. To learn more about this array, see UIBackgroundModes.

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>remote-notification</string>
</array>
```

**Sending a Silent Notification**

> The aps dictionary can also contain the `content-available` property. The `content-available` property with a value of 1 lets the remote notification act as a silent notification. When a silent notification arrives, iOS wakes up your app in the background so that you can get new data from your server or do background information processing. Users aren’t told about the new or changed information that results from a silent notification, but they can find out about out the next time they open your app.
>
> For a silent notification, take care to ensure there is no alert, sound, or badge payload in the aps dictionary. If you don’t follow this guidance, the incorrectly-configured notification might be throttled and not delivered to the app in the background, and instead of being silent is displayed to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the empty `completionHandler([])` to hide remote notification:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent 
                            notification: UNNotification, 
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: 
                            @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> 
                            Void)
{
    let userInfo:[AnyHashable:Any] =  notification.request.content.userInfo
    print("\(userInfo)")

    completionHandler([])
}
```